# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.by(sort.direction,string)

Tags: java, spring, jpa

getting the following error while trying to call my method which looks like **findAll(criteria, recordLimit, recordOffset,  Sort.by(DESC,MODIFIED_DATE))**
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.by(Lorg/springframework/data/domain/Sort$Direction;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/data/domain/Sort;

Using Spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar

Here is the relevant portion of the pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should post your POM file. Does this happen in a unit test? This sounds like you are compiling against one version but running against another.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: I agree with @Deadron. Something might be bringing in a different version of spring-data-commons at runtime. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and add its output to your question (not as a comment, edit the question and add it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `spring-data-commons` *and* `spring-data-commons-core`, the latter being very, very old. It has a conflicting class `Sort` that's being used at runtime instead of the one you want/need from `spring-data-commons`.

Remove the dependency on `spring-data-commons-core` and re-build.

Comment: Thanks..indeed it was the conflicting issues.After removing the older one, app is working fine